# when should I put var in front of function in js?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var output = function() {console.log('result')}
output();
</script>
```

If I changed to `output = function() {console.log('result')};` it still shows the right result, so my question is:

what is the difference between them? when should I put var in front of function in js? is that the same principle as `var` in front of variable?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript

Comment: Why don't you put `var` everywhere and see what happens? You learn by making mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is that the same principle as var in front of variable?"

Yes. output **is** a variable.

So I would suggest you use `var` in front of it when you *define* it. You could eventually change its value without using var. As in:

```
var A=1;
A=2;
A=A+1;
```

Consider the "script" of the funcion as the "value" of that variable.

```
var F=function() {console.log('one')};
// change it later
F=function() {console.log('two')};
```

(not suggesting you *do* this, but to show you it is 100% a var)

You are actually assigning to the variable named "output" a value of "function() {console.log('result')}" not as a string but as a script that gets executed. Note the semicolon at the end like in `var A=3;`

Now "inside" `output` there is the code that executes `console.log('result')`. (more or less, just to explain).

As you usually do not change that same function later (you can, and sometimes it is done) I really suggest you use `var` in front of it **every** time you define a function like this, even in cases when it is not strictly necessary, just to be safe you do not override an existing function.

This is a bit different from defining the function as:

```
function output() {console.log('result')}
```

Here there is no = sign, no assignment, no semicolon at the end. This is not a variable assignment but a function "definition" although results are similar, and you can call output() in both cases, there are differences. The main one I think is that function definitions are examined **before** executing the script line by line, while with assignment you really need to have the assignment line processed before you can use the function. So this:

```
output();

function output() {console.log('result')}
```

works. While this:

```
output(); // nope! output not defined yet!

var output=function() {console.log('result')}
```

doesn't. Variables are assigned or changed when the assignment instruction is read and interpreted.

```
// here A is undefined, B() prints 'ok'

var A=function() {console.log('first')};

// here A() prints 'first', B() prints 'ok' as usual

 A=function() {console.log('second')}; // change it

// here A() prints 'second', B() prints 'ok' as usual

function B() {console.log('ok')}

// same here A() prints 'second', B() prints 'ok'
```

Answer (score 3):

A function defined in a `script` tag is in the global scope (ie the `window` object in a browser context) so there is no difference in this case.

Inside a function block, however, is a different story. For example:

```
foo = function() {
    var foo = 1;
    console.log(foo);
}
foo();  // logs '1'
foo();  // logs '1'
```

But:

```
foo = function() {
    foo = 1;
    console.log(foo);
}
foo();  // logs '1'
foo();  // SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
```

Because `foo` wasn't defined locally, we overwrote the global object.

Comment: +1 for the auto-destroying function (to make it `mission impossible` style we could log a "This function will auto destruct itself in 10 seconds" and use a setTimeout :)

Answer (score 1):

You're in the global `window` scope, so there's no difference.

It doesn't matter what the type of the variable is.

If this is declared in functions, then there is a difference:

```
function name(){
    var a=1;
}
alert(a);
```

Here `a` will be undefined, as `var` declares the variable in the scope of the function.

As an excercise:

```
var a=2;
function name(){
    var a=1;
}
name();
alert(a);
```

This alerts `2` instead of `1`, since the middle `var` belongs in the scope of the function, which is separate from the global scope.

You can also modify global variables this way:

```
var a=2;
function name(){
    a=3;
}
name();
alert(a);
```

Also compare this with `let`, which limits it's scope to the block instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: Correct, but it's quite a narrow answer to say "In *this* example it's the same thing" when part of the question was about when there would be a difference

Answer (score 0):

Without `var` your variable will be declared as global variable which means it is available on other `JS` files too. In short If you declare a variable, without using `var`, the variable always becomes GLOBAL.

Answer (score 0):

Generally there is no difference because you are in the global `scope`, but in **ES5** there's a `strict mode`, which slightly changes the behavior of undeclared variables. In `strict mode`, assignment to an undeclared identifier (not putting `var` in front) is a ReferenceError.

For example:

```
"use strict";
myVariable = "foo"; // throws a ReferenceError
```

Answer (score 0):

Function or not function, here's [what MDN has to say about var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> The scope of a variable declared with var is the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside a function, the global scope (which is bound to the global object).
>
> Using var outside a function is optional; assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly declares it as a global variable (it is now a property of the global object). The difference is that a declared variable is a non-configurable property of the global object while an undeclared is configurable.

And you could also read about [the function statement here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Ffunction) and [the function operator here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Ffunction).

Cheers!